# Sharing a .blend file over 30mb

Tags: discussion

I understand that most of the time, .blend files will and should be under 30mb, and can be shared easily on questions, using [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) or [pasteall](http://pasteall.org).

Sometimes, though, and it's happened to me only twice, files will be over 30mb (the *pasteall* and *blend-exchange* limit).
Even if you strip it of all sorts of things to make it lighter...

It could be a scene with complex animations, many objects constrained together, or simply a scene where you don't run into the problem anymore when you delete some elements to make it lighter.

In these situations, what file-sharing website should we use?

Comment: Can you share an example for one? My first point would be that I'm not too keen at poking around large files.

Comment: I understand. I'd love to! (that's the point of the question, heheh...) How should I share it though? Care to recommend a service?

Comment: I more meant an example question, I would have suggested ways to possibly slim the file to isolate the problem. Dropbox is a safe good method.

Comment: This one for example; I think most questions about cell fracture will be over 20-30mb: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/linking-cell-fractured-fragments-together-with-rigid-body-constraints-set-as-br
File is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/md4v1zvhexbswqm/cell-fractured-dude-copy.blend?dl=0

Comment: For one, don't bake the physics. Simply provide the model and explain the process you followed or what you did and if you are indeed experiencing a problem someone will be able to reproduce it and continue from there.

Comment: I removed the physics, joined the original mesh then separated it back into individual blocks ready for simulation. 2.5MB

Comment: Ok, don't forget I'm not an expert, so I couldn't do what you did! Thanks a lot. I'll try to reproduce this and edit my question accordingly... Although it doesn't answer my question - and both dropbox and google drive are "temporary" file hosting sites

Comment: (now 200mb, THAT i can understand! but 32, heck, I'll try it... Noobs will be noobs)

Comment: @fabriced Also see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/allow-permanent-blend-file-hosting?rq=1, so I'd say this probably won't be a problem soon.

Comment: You can also try and reproduce the issue from scratch in a fresh file first. This way you can ensure the file contains the bare minimum amount of stuff required to reproduce the issue, and by experimenting you could very well end up finding a solution yourself.

Comment: That's a great tip!

Comment: @fabriced BTW, If you really really need to upload a large file to blend exchange, you can contact me and I can arrange it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok making a quick list of things you can do to cut your filesize, generally I'd say if it passes 20MB there is definitely something you can drop.

- Don't include baked simulations
- Don't include *large* video files
- Don't include *large* textures
- Delete unnecessary objects; no need to include your entire world if only your character's head is problematic

In general try to keep your files ~8MB. That's a good small size tho we might argue for a higher cap when and if we get that builtin functionality. Other notes are that your file should demonstrate the **specific** issue you're having. Nobody is going to volunteer their time to poke through your fancy assets and complex node trees.

Comment: Will try to update and refine this later, on mobile atm.

Comment: Ok. Also explain how to remove the bake, I couldn't find that anywhere online. I just tried to do what you did, starting by removing the physics, but the file is the same size...

Comment: @fabriced IIRC, exact steps. Select the camera, lamp and plane and hide with shift + h. next select any part of the model, hit shift + g and choose siblings. After that join them with Ctrl + J, now use Ctrl + I to inverse select all the empties and delete them, open the dopesheet and delete the keyframes then back into edit mode and use p > separate by loose objects. Finally unhide and you're ready to simulate again. I'm not sure if the model should be split however, your call but TL;DR, delete the constraint and keyframes.

Comment: @fabriced There should be a button labeled "Free bake" in the physics cache settings