# Compatibility Tag

Tags: discussion

I added the [compatibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility) tag for "[Blender's computer requirements](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139431/30849)".

There is a comment to close vote this question which states:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about **hardware**.

But the tag states:

> Questions about software, **hardware** and operating system compatibility with Blender.

Either doesn't make sense, can a mod please edit/remove the tag. Otherwise we should stop closing specifications question or make it clear in the help center.

Answer (score 3):

The thing we are trying to avoid with hardware questions is "questions" which typically turn into long-winded discussions and don't end up with any real answer. The close reason at [What should our custom off-topic close reasons be?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/what-should-our-custom-off-topic-close-reasons-be/322#322) elaborates a little bit:

> This questions appears to be off-topic because it is about the operating system, hardware, performance, or compatibility. These questions are considered off-topic because there is often no definitive answer, so they tend to require too much discussion to be suitable for Q&A format.  Try asking on [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support) for support instead.

I'd say it's okay for questions to pertain to hardware; our "hardware = off topic" policy originated more from a desire to have a more concrete definition for a class of questions which typically fell under either "too broad" or "opinion based" (e.g. most hardware recommendation questions) or "too localized" (e.g. extremely specific hardware problems). Somewhere in there there is a middle ground, and [those](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43700/599) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128693/599) [do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/20946/599) get asked and answered from time to time.

Since we've graduated and we don't have to care quite as much about closing everything that we can't answer right away, I'd say we don't need a hard and fast rule to close everything hardware or compatibility related as a matter of course anymore. Using "too broad"/"too localized", while more general and fuzzy, serves effectively the same purpose.

---

As for [this question in particular](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139431/599), I'd guess it's in "too broad"/"opinion based" territory, but it's really unclear, so I took the liberty of closing it as such.

Comment: I didn't say that the intentions and reasoning aren't clear to me. I just meant that the restriction *"off-topic because it is about the operating system, **hardware**, performance, or **compatibility**"* and having a **compatibility** tag are counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Leander I didn't state it very clearly (will edit), but I'm proposing that we ditch the "no hardware/compatibility" thing (it never actually made it to an official close reason in the first place) and simply close based on too broad or too localized.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I close as **too localized** ? I get the *too broad* option in the closing dialog, but not too localized. Is an 'other' commented reason?

Comment: @Leander Close> Off-topic because...> This question is too localized because...

Comment: ["Too-localized" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/241919) was replaced by other more specific close reasons since 2013, unless you're suggesting to use a custom close reason... //cc: @Leander